# using GetExtendedTcpTable in VB6

Tags: windows, winapi, vb6, network-programming

Please check Following statement of VB code

```
lReturn = GetExtendedTcpTable(Nothing, cb, False, 2, TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL, 0)
```

This throws error **122** that means **insufficient buffer size**. What should i do?

Comment: You need to give the correct size in second parameter. check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365928%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

Comment: @rags thank for reply. would u suggest any snippet i vb6.

Comment: Forget all about looking for examples in VB. There are many many examples in C++. Use those.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan But i have a old vb6 code in which i wanted to replace AllocateAndGetTcpExTableFromStack which is not supported by vista and later version of OS

Comment: So what? If the examples are in C++ and not in VB, you have two choices. 1. Learn how to read C++ and then translate to VB. 2. Work it our for yourself from the MSDN documentation. You are tying your hands behind your back if you refuse to read C++ code when working with Win32.

Comment: Anyway, it's actually not that hard to work it out from the MSDN docs. You did not show the declaration of `GetExtendedTcpTable`, nor how you prepared the parameters you pass. Specifically `cb`. It is clear though that the code can never work because you passed `Nothing` as the first parameter. That will always lead to failure.

Comment: i have studied the code that i have to call this function two times first for getting size and second for getting structure table, that will contain all the information related to TCP connections. Here is declaration **Private Declare Function GetExtendedTcpTable Lib "iphlpapi.dll" (ByRef pTcpTable As MIB_TCPTABLE, ByRef OutLen As Integer, ByVal Sort As Boolean, ByVal IpVersion As Integer, ByVal dwClass As Long, ByVal Reserved As Long) As Long**

Comment: OK, that's plausible. The documentation tells you what to do. When the function fails and returns `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER` (i.e. 122), then the second parameter tells you how large the buffer is. You then allocate a large enough buffer, and go around again. Please don't add the details in comments. That should be in the question. Anyway, you really ought to be able to work it out from the documentation. Do you know where to find the documentation?